# Paperclip Gem Not Uploading Images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have paperclip in several places throughout my application. I am trying to upload to attachments (two images) with one of my forms and it isn't providing any helpful information to as why It's not uploading successfully. I'm using paperclip 4.2.2.

The paperclip logs are as follows:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"XX", "listing_information_form"=>{"business_id"=>"11", "loan_id"=>"a09550000009thyAAA", "loan_name"=>"Growth!", "logo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8da1f4c3c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150622-11918-kkeln9>, @original_filename="woods_logo.png", @content_type="image/png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing_information_form[logo]\"; filename=\"woods_logo.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n">, "loan_image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8da1f4c280 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/RackMultipart20150622-11918-1sz4xkn>, @original_filename="woods_photo.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"listing_information_form[loan_image]\"; filename=\"woods_photo.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "terms_acceptance"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Next", "business_id"=>"11"}
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 11  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-1evafhf.png'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-obmo0e.png[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-obmo0e.png[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-obmo0e.png[0]' -auto-orient -resize "90x90" '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-obmo0e20150622-11918-11miz6z'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-obmo0e20150622-11918-11miz6z'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-l8tqr6.jpeg'
Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-1x7oerq.jpeg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-1x7oerq.jpeg[0]'
Command :: convert '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-1x7oerq.jpeg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "310x202>" '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-1x7oerq20150622-11918-fhthka'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-1x7oerq20150622-11918-fhthka'
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-bnp8ul.png'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-15i63c4.jpeg'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-19ipmvb.png'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-iso9kn.jpeg'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/92aeff05601e4e4ad9aded985f07727020150622-11918-1vhhwhy.png'
Command :: file -b --mime '/var/folders/1f/95lf0jwd0wjbl6zkvmdyffyw0000gn/T/b631013baf68cc1bc1e1a9d5a80163d220150622-11918-abrbba.jpeg'
   (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/businesses/12/listing_information_form/new
Completed 302 Found in 363ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
```

I just see the BEGIN/ROLLBACK attempts.

My controller code:

```
@listing_information_form = ListingInformationForm.create(listing_information_form_params)
if @listing_information_form.save && @listing_information_form.cancel_loan == nil
  redirect_to business_embedded_signing_path(@user)
elsif @listing_information_form.save && @listing_information_form.cancel_loan == true
  redirect_to business_root_path
else
  flash[:warning] = 'Unsuccessful'
  redirect_to :back
end

private

def listing_information_form_params
  params.require(:listing_information_form).permit(:business_id, :terms_acceptance, :logo_url, :picture_url, :business_profile, :loan_id, :loan_name, :logo, :loan_image, :cancel_loan)
end
```

My model:

```
has_attached_file :logo,
    :styles => { :original => "90x90" },
    :storage => :s3, 
    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
    :path => "account/:class/:railsid/:filename"
has_attached_file :loan_image,
    :styles => { :original => "310x202>" },
    :storage => :s3, 
    :url => ":s3_domain_url",
    :path => "account/class/:railsid/:filename"
```

Can anyone provide some information on the trace being provided by Paperclip? I'm uploading these files to s3 and haven't had any issues on the other forms throughout my application.

Comment: Normally you get `Unpermitted parameters:` because of what are you trying to send. Can you also put the code from `listing_information_form_params`? Maybe it helps. My thought on this is that you didn't permit `terms_acceptance` ..

Comment: @radubogdan I added terms into params in the controller. I posted the code here. No change in the issue other than the unpermitted params log doesn't come up anymore. I'm very confused about this whole thing.

Comment: There should some information after the ***ROLLBACK***. Can you post it?

Comment: @Pavan I added the two lines that come after the final rollback. It's just going through the render :back function.

Comment: What's happening with your `if` logic in the controller? Is your data passing validation? Also, you probably don't want to be calling `save` again in your `elsif`. I would store the result of that in a local variable and evaluate that in your `if` logic.

Comment: @ChrisPeters thanks for the feedback on my controller code- I'll work on improving that. Even when I removed the if elsif lines it still results in the same thing (rendering :back) and providing not validation or controller/model error.

Comment: What happens if you `puts @listing_information_form.errors.to_yaml` just before the redirect? Do you have any callbacks in your model that may accidentally be returning `false` and interrupting the transaction? I also notice above that it seems to be rolling back after inspecting the MIME of a `jpeg` file. Is everything OK with that file? What if you use a different one? Just trying to help you narrow it down more...

Comment: @ChrisPeters the to_yaml showed me the ridiculous error I should've been seeing. It had to do with the cancel_loan field. I really appreciate you helping me debug this- you saved me a lot of time and frustration.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments on the question...

> What happens if you `puts @listing_information_form.errors.to_yaml` just before the redirect?

@Questifer's answer:

> The `to_yaml` showed me the ridiculous error I should've been seeing. It had to do with the `cancel_loan` field. I really appreciate you helping me debug this- you saved me a lot of time and frustration.

Glad I could help! Sometimes just pecking at things with `puts` can be effective.

**BONUS:** My other suggestion would be to cache the value of `save` in a local variable like this so you don't accidentally run `save` twice:

```
@listing_information_form = ListingInformationForm.create(listing_information_form_params)
success = @listing_information_form.save

if success && @listing_information_form.cancel_loan == nil
  redirect_to business_embedded_signing_path(@user)
elsif success && @listing_information_form.cancel_loan == true
  redirect_to business_root_path
else
  flash[:warning] = 'Unsuccessful'
  redirect_to :back
end
```